# How to rotate cocos2D game into landscape mode in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I have an iPhone 4S (running iOS 5.1) & an iPhone 5 (running iOS 6.1). I noticed that when i try to open the `cocos2D` game, on the iPhone 4S running 5.1, the game is able to open perfectly fine in landscape mode.

However, when I try to open the same `cocos2D` game on my iPhone 5 running 6.1, the game is opened in portrait mode.

Is there any way that I can rotate the `cocos2D` game into landscape mode in the iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.

Some extra notes:

- The game is being pushed from a view controller in my test app.
- Since I am pushing the game from an iOS app, I have to support portrait mode in the "Support Interface Orientations" section. (If I was just doing the game, I would just easily set the Support Interface Orientation to landscape left/landscape right)

I have also tried different methods such as for iOS 6 such as:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

But it has given me different results when I tried those methods.

Ideally, I would like the app to be locked in the Portrait mode and game to be locked into Landscape mode.

So, I'm wondering if it is possible to have an app that remains locked in the portrait mode and the game locked in landscape mode (for both iOS 5 & iOS 6) when opened?

Here's a link to a sample project I was working on:

http://www.4shared.com/zip/yEAA1D_N/MyNinjaGame.html

Answer (score 2):

I just set the orientation modes in Xcode ("Summary" tab on your target) to landscape left and right. Then for every UIViewController I added this:

```
// Autorotation iOS5 + iOS6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing for landscape in my cocos2d game (on iOS 6.1):

```
//This is in the AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
//change to 'return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);' for portrait
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, stenger98. I have tried this method and it didn't resolve the issue. This was,actually,one of the first method I implemented. Is there any other suggestions that you may have? There is a 4shared link to I posted above that you can use to try it out.

Comment: Okay, I'll download it and test it out as soon as I get home. Just to be clear you're trying to get the app to be only landscape on iOS 6.1?

Comment: I want *only* the game to be only in landscape for iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.1. iOS 5.0+ is fine, but the problem lies in iOS 6.0+. The rest of the app needs to be in portrait. Keep in mind, the device and the iOS Simulator can produce different results, in my experience. As long as it works on the device, no problem. :)

Comment: May I ask why you want the startup to be portrait and then the game to be landscape? Because I did some research and I think that this isn't working because of a bug.

Comment: Why do you have to push the game from a view controller?

Comment: Because the contents of the app isn't optimized for landscape view, therefore the app will look sketchy if put into landscape view. The game is the only part that needs to be in landscape. Another method that I have used was loading the game from a Modal View Controller, but again, the issue with the orientation occurs.

Comment: You could just make the app part portrait without the model view controller.